# Running MSIEXEC on non-administrator login

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-installer

I need to get an msi installed on a number of machines. I've written a script to check the version and deploy if necessary, but it doesn't seem to like the msiexec call. Can msiexec be run from a limited user, or only administrators? Can someone point me in the right direction.

Alternatively, what's a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the "Always install with elevated privileges" setting in Group Policy, either as a Domain Policy if you have AD, otherwise as a local policy on the individual PCs themselves.

Find it in User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Installer.

Comment: So, that affects all uses of MSIEXEC? I've got a VBS that runs on startup and installs an MSI that lives on a server (if the MSI has a higher version).

Could you please confirm?

Comment: @Tim: If it's running at startup (not login) the script is running w/ system level permissions.